# Formula to show text value in a cell if not matched on two ranges in different tabs

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, match, formula

I'm working on a Google sheet, and I need a formula which will display a text value from a cell (AA3), if the text value is NOT matched on two ranges from two different tabs in the same workbook.

The formula will help me display which staff haven't yet been allocated their dive jobs at the dive centre I run.

Here's a screenshot which makes it clear what I'm talking about.

[image: screenshot to help]

Comment: `=IF(OR(COUNTIF(Sheet2!range,AA3)=0,COUNTIF(Sheet3!range,AA3)=0),AA3,"")`

Comment: Scott, you're the man! Thanks.

Comment: Firstly Scott, thanks again for your help. I was a tad hasty there though, and after testing, the name value still appears unless the name is entered in ranges O4:O18 on BOTH sheets. Is there a way to adjust it so the name value will not appear if it matches on either sheetA or sheet B?

Comment: Change the `OR` to `AND`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to do this for all the employees, you can use regexreplace to replace the values that are already present in those arrays and leave only the available names:

```
=split(REGEXREPLACE(join(";",master!$AA$3:$AE$3),join("|",unique({alladin!$O$4:$O$18;mermaid!$O$4:$O$18})),""),";")
```

To explain: you first join AA3:AE3 to give it your starting values, then you join the two ranges from the other two sheets in a literal array and wrap them in unique. When you join the two arrays, you use the regex symbol for `OR` which is `|` .

Using regexreplace, it basically defines that if any of the names appear in the original list of values, replace them with null,  thus leaving you with the remaining names that have been unused.

I created the example above using the sheet names you showed in your example photo

[image]

Comment: Thanks Scott, and Aurielle, both very helpful. Scott swapping to the AND did the business, and your formula is doing everything I wanted it to. Thanks again.